# Input Manager 2 Players with 2 Controllers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, controller, keyboard

I have a game with 2 Players who can shoot, the problem is right now when i press joystick button 0 on joystick 1 they both shoot. Apparently Joy Num only works when you use Joystick Axis but i don't want the axis to shoot i want button 0.

[image: Input Manager]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a code-related issue, but with out your code, we cant help you...

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not code problem because for Player 1 and Player 2 Movement it works find using Axis but using buttons doesn't work.

Comment: Although you may be pretty sure, it's not something you can rule out without checking first. You could have still made a mistake with the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current Unity InputManager.
You should really try to take a look to the new Input System
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem
(still in beta testing).

PS. Right now you can actually use multiple joystick
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html

with specific joystick buttons name
joystick 1 button 0
instead of
joystick button 0

Answer (score 1):

Mah kind of answered it already, but it looks like the problem is just your "Alt Positive Button" field should be

```
joystick 1 button 0
```

instead of

```
joystick button 0
```